# How to show highlight in LineChart only when chart in press state or drag state?

Tags: mpandroidchart

I need to repeat similar behavior to Google Fit charts. When chart is pressed or dragging - we show highlighter on chart. Right after finger don't touch chart - remove highlighter. I found "onTap" variable for tap on chart - but it's work only when we tap and then remove finger from screen. But i need to show highlighter right after finger touched chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MakerView and OnChartGestureListener can help, onChartGestureEnd tells when should the marker should disappear:

```
final MyMarkerView marker = new MyMarkerView(this, R.layout.custom_marker_view);
chart.setMarker(marker);
chart.setDrawMarkers(true);
chart.setOnChartGestureListener(new OnChartGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChartGestureStart(MotionEvent me,
        ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {
        chart.setDrawMarkers(true);
            for(int i = 0; i < chart.getLineData().getDataSetCount(); ++i) {
                ILineDataSet set = chart.getLineData().getDataSetByIndex(i);
                set.setHighlightEnabled(true);
            }
     // Thanks to Mr. SoulReaver313 !                   
     chart.highlightValue(chart.getHighlightByTouchPoint(me.getX(), me.getY())); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onChartGestureEnd(MotionEvent me,
        ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {
        chart.setDrawMarkers(false);
            for(int i = 0; i < chart.getLineData().getDataSetCount(); ++i) {
                ILineDataSet set = chart.getLineData().getDataSetByIndex(i);
                set.setHighlightEnabled(false);
            }
        chart.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChartLongPressed(MotionEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChartDoubleTapped(MotionEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChartFling(MotionEvent me1, MotionEvent me2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChartScale(MotionEvent me, float scaleX, float scaleY) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChartTranslate(MotionEvent me, float dX, float dY) {

    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: It's working good for MarkerView. But can we do the same with Highlight lines?

Comment: also i have trouble with behavior. When i just press on chart i can see custom marker at the last point and then i drag i can see new points highlighted. So i have 2 problems: highlight line doesn't syncronized with marker and when i undrag chart and then press chart at the other place i can see highlighted previous spot

Comment: It is similar to make highlight behave same as maker, when gesture start, update the highlight enable to true, andwhen gesture end, update highlight enable to false and invalidate. Code is updated. @SoulReaver313

Comment: Thanks! But what about highlight only the value that "finger is touching"? If i will press on chart i will se previous value and then i will drag then i will see values that i'm pointing to

Comment: It must be some bug! I didn't notice this until your comment, I will debug it later.

Comment: Please respond if you will find the issue. This charts is really such a headache for me :/

Comment: Please tell me you have a plan :D

Comment: @SoulReaver313 I have a plan but it doesn't work as expected :( the reason is found, because hightlighter is updated AFTER onChartGestureStart, so when the chart is updated, it is still using the last hightlighter. hightligher is updated when tap or move, so the chart draw correctly after tap or move.

Comment: I found that we can use in onChartGestureStart this `lineChart.highlightValue(lineChart.getHighlightByTouchPoint(me.x, me.y))` so we highlight the closest entry on touch. But in our implementation it's not highlighted on touch but insted highlighted after dragging to next value. It's because this `for` cicle with `isHighlightEnabled` logic. If we simply remove this logic then it's working as expected. Can you help me make "highlight only when touched" logic with using it?

Comment: by the way i'm using Kotlin

Comment: God. I'm silly. You just need to enable highlight before highlighting a new value... So if you add `lineChart.highlightValue(lineChart.getHighlightByTouchPoint(me.x, me.y))` after `set.isHighlightEnabled = true` in `onStartGesture` then you highlight exact value that you touching. Dragging included.

Comment: Oh, yes! You are correct, I was in a wrong direction, tried to found the suitable touche event which is before hightlight updated, but you just reset the highlight!!! The code is updated @SoulReaver313

Comment: Yeah we did it. My question is fully solved :)